# Detecting eigenvals of opposite sign

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, spectral-theory

Consider a large (in the region of 500 by 500 up to 2000 by 2000) real, square symmetric matrix.

What would be a good way of algorithmically determining if it has any pair of eigenvals with opposite signs? I want to avoid finding the whole spectrum if at all possible.

Comment: what do you mean by " any pair of eigenvalues with opposite signs" ? Would it be ok to just testing if the max eigenvalue is positive and the min eigenvalue is negative ? For there are algorithms to find the largest eigenvalue. Or does "pair" means "same absolute value, opposite sign" ?

Comment: I want to check if any two eigenvalues have opposite sign. Yes examining the largest and smallest would do it, but is this the best way?

Comment: at least you can very efficiently get the largest. I don't know for the "largest negative".  The mood caused to the transform by the eigenvalues sign is that orientation might or might not be respected by the transform it you twickle it along the appropriate axis: intuitively it sounds as systematic as the search of each eigenvalue (but I might be wrong).

Comment: I think this may boil down to finding the condition number...

Comment: nope, scratch that, it was wrong.

Comment: scratch, scratch, scratch :-D

Comment: guys: are methods to find largest eigenvalue indeed all finding the largest in absolute value ? (e.g. eigenvector = $M^\infty.v$ , with $v$ a random vector).